# Repair GRUB after removing /boot /boot/efi partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I had ubuntu installed on M2 SSD:

- /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot
- /dev/nvme0n1p2 /
- /dev/nvme0n1p3 /boot/efi
- /dev/nvme0n1p4 /home

Tried to install Windows on the second SATA SSD, then deleted the /boot and /boot/efi partitions, everything broke (not surprising).
Formatted the disk with Windows, merged the /boot/efi partition with /home and tried to restore the GRUB, but it didn't work.
In the BIOS, you can see that ubuntu is installed on the M2 SSD, but when I try to start the PC, I get into the BIOS. I tried instructions from the Internet, but I don't really understand what and why.

Anyone help me to restore GRUB without Ubuntu reinstall please

Comment: UEFI has to have an ESP - efi system partition.  With multiple drives, you only have to have one, but often best to have an ESP on every drive, if only as backup. Entry in UEFI is remembered & probably trying to boot from deleted ESP. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair